# Joining Excel data with database data not working

Tags: database, tableau-api

The column in the database is varchar, has values like 3456, 2007, AD50, G600

I have the same data in an Excel sheet I'm trying to blend with the database data in tableau.

When the data type is set to string in tableau it picks only the ones starting with letters and ignores those like numbers. If I change the data type to numbers, the opposite happens: numbers match & those with letters get dropped.

How do I set this up correctly so when I data blend the 2 sets of data the numbers match & the letters also match?

Comment: Probably you need to convert your column of data in Excel to Text-Only format (select column, goto Data, Text To Columns, next, next, select "Text" as column data format, Finish.)  Then all your numeric values will show up with a little green triangle indicating that they are actually text values.  After that the blend should work.

Comment: Will try that. Thanks.